# Always route file path to Desktop

Tags: vba

Can I use a VBA reserved word to always go to desktop regardless of machine/PC a macro is ran from?

Example:

PC1
“C\Users\Dell\Desktop\MyFile”

PC2
“C\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\MyFile”

Can I just remove Dell or Toshiba and insert a reserved word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ENVIRON function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/environ-function) allows you to retrieve any SET environment variable.

```
'C\Users\Dell\Desktop\MyFile
environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MyFile"

'C\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\MyFile
"C\Users\" & environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\MyFile"
```

Go to a CMD prompt and type SET for a list of current environment variables. Yes, you can set up your own. The exact method will depend somewhat on your windows version and active directory status so do an internet search for your particular situation.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks Jeeped

Comment: Be careful with those 'smart quotes' found in the original samples. Those are not accepted as quote characters in any code editor.